# Can you awake app with Bluetooth LE?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

After a very massive exploring of the area , where what we wanted is to have region monitoring+ exchanging data with bluetooth hardware , i really could not understand what is possible and whats not.

We manage to develop the hardware to be `iBeacon+BLE`, but seems that the `iOS` is the problem.

Using iBeacon, i know i can detect region when my app is closed(or background) .
I was trying to detect region when its closed with `iBeacon`,than when in region, switch to **BLE IN BACKGROUND** to exchange data. So, that didn't work,when discover the `iBeacon` in background, i can't also connect to it via `BLE`,only in foreground .

Than i was thinking, why i can't register to a BLE device, and also awake an app when its closed, when i am closed to a BLE with a certain UUID. 
I have read almost anything, and Apple seems to have so many rules, that you can't eventually understand if you can or can't do that, and how .

//too many rules
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1

//no bottom line :

[How to wake up iOS app with bluetooth signal (BLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932090/how-to-wake-up-ios-app-with-bluetooth-signal-ble)

So , can it be done ??? if not, can you even switch from iBeacon when enter region to BLE ? if i do that in background, he can't find the BLE device,only in foreground .

Comment: Assuming your code and hardware are correct, iBeacons should be able to trigger your application in the background, and even while closed. Bluetooth LE runs on a different level than apps, and therefore is constant. Once your application registers for notifications from it, it will always be alerted when entering/exiting a region.

Comment: Thanks . I dont understand your answer. I know that i can get alert from beacon in background,i know also that i can connect to a BLE, but i have never seen a way to register to BLE(not beacon!!) to get background notifications. also, when beacon awake app in background, you can't scan for BLE than in background. So, how you answer related to these problems ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to that question in the meantime?