# Wake App from background mode on BLE interaction

Tags: ios, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wish to get app from background mode to foreground mode on BLE(*non ibeacon*) device interaction.

I have added Bluetooth-central Bluetooth-peripheral under `UIBackgroundModes` in the `Info.plist`. In background mode `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`: method is being called.

How to open my app under this situation? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You can't "open" your app (bring it to the foreground) but you can execute in the background to process the data.  What is happening? What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932090/how-to-wake-up-ios-app-with-bluetooth-signal-ble in this link it is mentioned 'iOS will open your app for you if it detects a UUID that matches your app. The app only needs to be installed, it doesn't have to be running'. 
So, I wish to get the app in foreground mode on trigger of the BLE device already connected to the app. Is this possible?

Comment: No, the only way that an app can enter the foreground is if the user taps its icon, taps a notification from your app or taps a link that contains your app's url scheme.  When your app executes in the background in response to a BLE event you can post a local notification prompting the user to bring your app to the foreground but you cannot force it

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I have done the same thing currently.